# Conditions for subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a ring $R$. Suppose that $S \subset R$ and $0,1 \in S$. It is also given that $a + b \in S$ and $a \bullet b \in S$ for all $a,b \in S$.Is this sufficient in showing that $S$ is a subring of $R$? Do we need to show that the inverse of $a$ is in S for all $a \in S$?

Comment: @rschwieb OK, I've moved the comment down.

Comment: @AdamHughes fantastic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do. Otherwise $\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\subset\Bbb Z$ would be a ring, which it is not.